# Why can't I reach this column in my model in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my client.rb:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurance_provider
end
```

This is most easily explained by a console session:

```
1.9.3p448 :005 > Client.joins(:insurance_provider).first.insurance_provider

  Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "insurance_providers" ON "insurance_providers"."client_id" = "clients"."id" ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  InsuranceProvider Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "insurance_providers".* FROM "insurance_providers" WHERE "insurance_providers"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 6]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<InsuranceProvider id: 2, client_id: 6, name: "Blue Cross Blue Shield", member_id: "123456789", copay: 20, effective_on:     "2013-07-08", created_at: "2013-10-23 14:40:00", updated_at: "2013-10-23 14:40:00">]> 


1.9.3p448 :006 > Client.joins(:insurance_provider).first.insurance_provider.copay

  Client Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "insurance_providers" ON "insurance_providers"."client_id" = "clients"."id" ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError:   InsuranceProvider Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "insurance_providers".* FROM "insurance_providers" WHERE "insurance_providers"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 6]]
undefined method `copay' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_InsuranceProvider:0x007fae3e8e9d80>
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/collection_proxy.rb:22:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/rabdelaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

why can't I reach the `copay` column??

Comment: how is `insurance_provider` defined on `Client`. looks like this is not configured properly.

Comment: updated the question. Client has_many :insurance_provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_many` relations should always be plural: `insurance_providers`

if you do a `client.insurance_providers` it will return an array.

so this should work: `Client.joins(:insurance_providers).first.insurance_providers.first.copay`

Comment: ok, there's something really screwy here. I changed my model like you said but now I get this: `Client.joins(:insurance_provider).first.insurance_providers.copay
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'insurance_provider' was not found on Client; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: i think it should then be `joins(:insurance_providers)` plural as well. i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

`Client.joins(:insurance_provider).first.insurance_provider` is an array of InsuranceProvider objects, so you have pick the object from an array and send the copay message.

Also FYI when we use has_many association according to rails, it should be plural, that is your model should look like this,

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurance_providers
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your relation is defined as a one-to-many, with the `insurance_provider` on the many side. In short, you're not getting back a single object, you're getting back a collection. Notice in the stack trace, it says "unidentified method 'copay' for ...ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy...". That's one indicator right there. So, what you'll need to do is iterate over the collection using `.each`, or invoke `.first` or `.last` or whatever to get the value you need. Basically that collection proxy behaves like an array so you can treat it pretty much as such.

Comment: @Ramy Yes, but you're invoking it on the `Client` model, not the `insurance_providers` association. As I and phoet said, since `insurance_providers` is defined as a `has_many`, you end up with a collection of objects. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm starting to see the problem now - I need to a single insurance_provider with a max(:effective_on) date. Something like `client.insurance_providers.maximum(:effective_on).copay`. Look out for another question on SO if I can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!